# How to create this effect in Premiere or After Effects

Tags: after-effects, editing, adobe, special-effects, premiere-pro

Is there a a name for this effect where the pace of the footage is changing as seen in this video?

?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi there. What is your question? Is it "how to create" or is it "what is the name"? Please edit your post to clarify

Comment: Looks like speed ramping on each beat https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gtrcAKl1Rfs